# Rails4 unable to render the correct partial on remote call

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

the remote link is working fine , reaching correctly the Controller with `js format` , then I am trying to render different partials based on the received `params[:id]` but something is wrong in my writing ... don't get it ..

in my layout view

```
<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
  <div id="page-content">
    <div id='wrap'>
      <%= yield %>
    </div> <!--wrap -->
  </div> <!-- page-content -->
  <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
```

my `SheetsController.rb` is :

```
 class SheetsController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :html, :js

    def show
      sheet = Sheet.find(params[:id])
      @sheet = "sheets/_#{sheet.name}.html.erb"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          render template: "sheets/sample.js.erb"  
        }
        format.html {
          render template: @sheet  
        }
      end    
    end
  end
```

in my `sheets/sample.js.erb` , I wrote

```
$('#page-content #wrap').html("<%=j render partial: @sheet %>");
```

the error is :

```
  ArgumentError - The partial name (sheets/_sample-0.html.erb) 
 is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts 
 with underscore, and is followed by any combination of let ters, 
 numbers and underscores.:
```

My views structure is

```
app
   - views
       - sheets
           sample.js.erb
           _sample-0.html.erb
           _sample-1.html.erb
           _sample-2.html.erb
           show.html.erb
```

is it wrong ?  thanks for feedback

Comment: could you please add some more `error-log` like with `filename` and `line-number` where error occured?

Comment: ok try only this `@sheet = "_#{sheet.name}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change

`@sheet = "sheets/_#{sheet.name}.html.erb"`

to

`@sheet = "sheets/#{sheet.name}.html.erb"`

Please let me know how it goes.

P.S. I tested to confirm that the inclusion of the extension .html.erb or exclusion of the extension does not affect the partial rendering. But if I included the underscore, I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue reading again the error message ...  my partials are named  : sample-0  sample-1 sample-2  ,'-' is PROHIBITED ..
changing the name to letters , numbers and underscores... is the trick

sample_0  sample_1  sample_2

Comment: Great news. I like your question. Interesting idea. Good luck with it.